# Can a Chihuahua and a Great Dane breed the "old fashioned way?"

Tags: reproduction, anatomy

I saw this vid:

https://youtu.be/eu2qe-FNtjg

And this question crossed my mind.  The dog in the video seems to be boxer sized... And I wonder if that strategy would work with something a little bigger....
Also, this is obvious, but let me clarify: 'I'm thinking about  a FEMALE Great Dane and a MALE Chihuahua. (The other way arround, we would get a Chihuahuaburger before anything even happened... And would be animal cruelty. ) Since they're the same species ( a dog, aka Canis lupus familiaris) that means they can make  viable offspring, rigth?

Comment: I'm not watching this video but yes, it is possible with artificial insemination or if you support the small dog during mating. Chihuahua and Great Dane might be a bit ambitious for the latter, though.

Comment: I don't think artificial insemination is very "old fashioned" ;) lol.  But thanks. What sort of support? like... putting the chihuahua on the Great Dane's back? (that's the way the chihuahua does it in the video, it jumps on top of the boxer, on it's own...)